# Passing the JQuery string to Worldpress URL

Tags: permalinks, pages, url-rewriting, redirect

I have already followed the tutorial here: http://www.rlmseo.com/blog/passing-get-query-string-parameters-in-wordpress-url/
But it still doesn't work.

In the function.php, my code is

```
    //decode wordpress url to jquery string
    function add_query_vars($aVars) {
    $aVars[] = "lastName"; 
    return $aVars;
    }

    // hook add_query_vars function into query_vars
    add_filter('query_vars', 'add_query_vars');

    function add_rewrite_rules($aRules) {
    $aNewRules = array('^physician-profile/([^/]*)/?' => 'physician-profile?lastName=$matches[1]');
    $aRules = $aNewRules + $aRules;
    return $aRules;
    }
    // hook add_rewrite_rules function into rewrite_rules_array
    add_filter('rewrite_rules_array', 'add_rewrite_rules');
```

I would like my link from

```
    physician-profile?lastName=Rae-Lee
```

to

```
    physician-profile/Rae-Lee.
```

In the pysician-profile page, my code is: but I don't know why I put it here. It seems like just return the value of lastName.

```
     if(isset($wp_query->query_vars['lastName'])) {
     $lastNameS=(urldecode($wp_query->query_vars['lastName']));
```

In the main page,I linked the physician link as

```
    physician-profile/Rae-Lee,
```

but it keep going to the home page.When I tried changed the link as

```
    physician-profile?lastName=Rae-Lee,
```

it goes directly that page, but the URL doesn't change.
As a wordpress beginner, could you point it out which part I did wrong?
Or do I need other codes?
Thank  you for your help!

Comment: It seems, you did not call/hook the `add_rewrite_rules` function...? Or did I just overlook that?

Comment: Oh, I forgot to paste and copy them. Already added them in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tutorial is outdated and it seems it missed to flush the rules.

```
function add_rewrite_rule_and_tag() {

    global $wp_rewrite;

    add_rewrite_rule( '^physician-profile/([^/]*)/?', 'physician-profile?lastName=$matches[1]', 'top' );
    add_rewrite_tag( '%lastName%','([^&]+)' );

    if ( ! isset( $wp_rewrite->rules['^physician-profile/([^/]*)/?'] ) )
        $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();

    return;

}

add_action( 'init', 'add_rewrite_rule_and_tag', 99 );
```

You can access the query var `lastName´ with

```
gloabl $wp_query;
$lastName = $wp_query->query_vars['lastName'];
```

Comment: Thank you Ralf, but I tried to put codes in the function.php, and then nothing happened. I even used rewrite analyzer but it the new rule didn't show in the analyzer.

Comment: I figured it out. Thank the link should be index.php?pagename=physician-profile..balabala